# Python 3.2 Tic Tac Toe Game Replay?

Tags: python

i programmed a tic tac toe game in python and it works perfectly fine and everything. so i was wondering, can you somehow program the game to say, "`Do you wish to play again?`" after the computer wins or if you win?

in my game, once the computer wins or you win, it doesn't say anything and i want the game to ask the player if they want to play again. gracias(:

Comment: do you know what the code would be or anything? i'm not sure what i would type or something.

Comment: What have you tried? You need some sort of function that detects when the game is over in order to show your message. Maybe you can show some code so we can help out

Comment: I'm sorry is this just some console python game? Are you really using pygame?

Comment: Please stop asking these questions until you have read and digested the articles suggested by Wilduck on your last question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197157/python-3-2-tic-tac-toe-game-issue#comment14697977_11197157

Comment: i have a question about my game.. huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have something like this at some point in your game (typically when a game ends):

```
answer = raw_input("Would you like to play it again?") // Get the user answer

if answer == 'yes':
  restart_game()     // if answer is 'yes' play the game again
else:
  close_game()       // else close the game
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your game inside a larger loop, something like this. Ideally you have your code broken up into functions so it will be easy to do.

```
def play_game():
    print 'playing the game'

answer = 'y'
while answer.lower() == 'y':
    play_game()
    answer = raw_input("Do you wish to play again? (y/n)")

print 'the end.'
```

There are other variations of this loop, but this should give you an idea of the basic structure.

Note that this will quit if the input is anything other than `Y` or `y` .. you'll have to think about if that's good enough, or if you want to handle other input for `n` or `N` or longer replies/strings. The prompt currently *implies* that only these two `(y/n)` are valid options - so this is something for you to think about and solve.